# How to make cookies accept button and functionality for different different pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

On my website, I have cookies accept button and functionality. it's working fine. but I need some kind of change. like I need every page different kind of cookies button. for example, if I am on the homepage if I click the cookies accept button it should close and stored my cookies only for that particular page. but when I navigate to another page it should show. so that the cookies accept button should work on that page only.

how to make it this. I tried some ways but it's not working. help me to fix this.

this is the codes now I am using it.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        if (getCookie('popupCookie') != 'submited') {
            if (getCookie('popupCookie') != 'closed') {
                $('.floating-banner').css("display", "flex").hide().fadeIn();
            }
        }

        $('#close-banner').click(function () {
            $('.floating-banner').fadeOut();
            setCookie('popupCookie', 'closed', 1);
        });

        function getCookie(cname) {
            var name = cname + "=";
            var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
                var c = ca[i];
                while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
                    c = c.substring(1);
                }
                if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                    return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
                }
            }
            return "";
        }

        function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
            var d = new Date();
            d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
            document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
        }

    });
```

Comment: That seems like really bad ux

Comment: No. actually we have a small kind of product popup. its different messages for different pages. for that reason, I need this.